# Can I remove the locations/views from the Windows Explorer pane in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is it possible to remove the locations/views from Windows Explorer in the folder pane on the left? Example: Favorites, Libraries, Homegroup, etc.

I'd like to be able to choose which categories I see here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change these in Windows 7 directly.

However [this](http://lifehacker.com/275723/tweak-your-explorer-sidebar-with-findexer-and-placesbar-editor) LifeHacker article mentions an application called FindeXer that does allow customizing the side bar and is compatible with Vista. I am not sure if it will work on Windows 7 thought.

Answer (score 0):

Often it will be a per item process to add/remove items from the Windows Explorer navigation pane. Here are some links from superuser or other sites for some of the more commonly removed items:

1. [Remove Libraries from the Windows Explorer navigation pane.](https://superuser.com/questions/30754/how-to-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorer)
2. [Remove HomeGroup from the navigation pane.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/disable-and-turn-off-homegroup-services-to-hide-or-remove-home-group-from-windows-7-explorer/)
3. [Remove Favorites from the Windows Explorer navigation pane.](https://superuser.com/questions/47633/remove-favorites-in-windows-7-explorer-navigation-pane)

1 & 2 are sufficient for me, as those are the most annoying in terms of not using them and taking up so much space. =)

*[Feel free to edit above and add any other methods/items. Also, the accepted answer might have been true previously, but not any longer. Note that the above do require either fiddling with services or the registry.]*