# How to open command window from documents library?

Tags: windows-7, libraries

Normally in Windows Explorer, I can open a command window by shift right-clicking in the folder. I love this feature.

However sometimes this item is missing from the context menu. This is really frustrating. On investigation, it's precisely when window is labelled 'documents library'.

How can I fix this? Either so the 'open command window' items shows up in both cases, or to force all Windows Explorer windows to be of the first kind.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Libraries are potentially a union of many folders at the same time.  How would your system know which member folder to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I browse windows 7 libraries from the command prompt?](http://superuser.com/questions/203639/can-i-browse-windows-7-libraries-from-the-command-prompt)

Comment: @Zoredache what do you mean? I understand there's both 'public documents' and 'my documents', but there's only one folder on my computer called `felicitous-desktop`, it's at `C:\Users\Matt\Documents\felicitous-desktop`.

Comment: @Raystafarian that's not my question! I'm asking how do I open a command window at `C:\Users\Matt\Documents\felicitous-desktop` (that's an ordinary folder) from a Windows Explorer of the second kind.

Comment: +1 because I did not know of the existence of that shortcut.

Comment: The documents folder is a [library](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/managing-your-documents) which is why it doesn't work. You should either not include that folder in the library, or move that folder to a different place `c:\folder`

Comment: Check [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/30754/remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorer) to disable the library feature

Answer (score 5):

I located a solution [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0c47b830-3cb1-4f7a-bcf2-294ff4d90e2d/i-cannot-open-command-line-in-libraries) for adding the 'Open Command Window Here' option to the Context Menu for Library Folders.

> You just have to add a few registry keys:
>
> ```
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd (set value to what you want to be displayed on the right click menu, e.g. "Open command window here"
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd\command (set value to "cmd.exe /k")
> ```
>
> If you're not familiar with the registry editor, you can just copy the following text into Notepad, save it as whatever.reg, and double click it:
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd]
> @="Open command window here"
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd\command]
> @="cmd.exe /k"
> ```

I did it in a slightly different way, exactly copying the keys and values that appeared in the `cmd` key within the Directory/background folder. The result is a little different, as the command window is opened at the location you expect (the current folder), rather than "C:\Windows\System32" as with the above.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd]
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

To address the comment by @Zoredache, this ambiguity exists only when the folder you are viewing is the union of folders, as indicated when the header section of your folder has something like this.

[image]

In this case, the location that the Command Window opens to is whichever directory in your Library is set as the 'Default Save Location'. Other than that, it behaves as expected.

Comment: Your registry script is invalid. There must be a a header such as `REGEDIT4` or `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00` to allow the .REG file to work. After I did that, it worked fine. Apparently I am not allowed to edit and fix this

Comment: Great work! I tried to make the edit and I believe it is awaiting review.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, Libraries doesn't have the 'Open command window here' option like normal folders. But it's possible to add it by modifying the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd]
@="@shell32.dll,-8506"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

This registry script will enable the familiar option in Libraries. To install it, save the above as a .reg file and run it.

If for some reason it doesn't work or you want to remove it, save the following as a .reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\cmd]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might get you close: The page has a download for a .reg file that purportedly disables libraries in Win7, This oughtta prevent any situations where you are getting the library style explorer windows, but its a bit of a kludge

http://lifehacker.com/5354879/disable-the-new-libraries-feature-on-windows-7

Normally I would prefer to use (and recommend) pages which will actually list the steps rather than offering only a .reg file. I've seen this .reg on a few sites, but all of them decline to include a run down of the changes made, saying it is more complicated than a normal registry hack. I would strongly recommend reading through the .reg file first to be sure it's doing what you expect.