# Remove "Favorites" in Windows 7 Explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites

Is there a way to remove the "Favorites" item at the top of the navigation pane in Explorer in Windows 7? It really bugs me that it wastes so much space, and I can't find a way to remove it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are links to remove any or all parts of the navigation bar so you can customize it the way you like. Personally I remove Homegroup and Libraries as I like having My Computer Network and Favorites. As for favorites if you click the favorites it will bring you to the folder that contains your shortcuts and you can ad or remove anything you like. Personally besides the the computer and network browsing shortcuts this is the best, you could actually remove everything but favorites and add your computer and network folders in it.

Anyway here are the links and the site they all come from is a GREAT resource.
First off to stay on topic this is the link to remove Favorites then i will follow with the instructions for the rest in the list of links below they all contain the registry information on how to remove or ad them and if you are so inclined you can create a .reg file to edit them on the fly or to create a.reg file to bring back anything you removed (that is if you know how to create on I wont get into that here):

[Favorites,](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/38933-favorites-add-remove-navigation-pane.html)

I am a new user so i am only able to post one URL so if you want to edit anything else read the whole post this links you to and at the bottom their are links to do the same for all the other nav options available.

Comment: +1. You can add other links as comments, or update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - As John T said, there is no way to remove just the favourite section - the following refers to the whole bar.

To shrink the favourites bar, click on the separator line and drag it further to the left.

If you want to remove it completely do the following:

1. Click "Organise"
2. Expand the "Layout" option
3. Untick the "Navigation pane" option.

[image]

Comment: Well, unfortunately I like the navigation pane, I just don't want the Favorites thing taking up space. I'll just have to live with it, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this: http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/09/02/how-to-remove-and-hide-libraries-group-from-navigation-pane-of-windows-7-explorer/

But use 0xa9**4**00100 instead. I've seen different values for this in various places. I assume it is a bit flag.... What I would do is change just the 0->4 digit in what ever value you have there currently. If it doesn't work try the value I gave. Do remember or backup the original key in case you get some weird effect though.

Props to i-g for the link above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to completely disable it yet, but you can hide the entire navigation pane, or delete items from favorites to make that section smaller.

Comment: "yet" - what versions of Windows 7 does this answer apply to, when did it change?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to [remove the Libraries dropdown](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/08/05/how-to-disable-and-remove-libraries-from-windows-7-explorer/), but I don't know if there's a similar way to get rid of Favorites. Unfortunately, I can't test it myself, since I'm not running Windows 7 yet. Here it is:

It seems pretty straightforward. Just remember to back up the entire parent of the registry key you're modifying before you make any changes. (Just  select the parent key/folder and export it to a .reg file.)

Answer (score 0):

I searched for “favorites” in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID  part of the registry, and I found key {323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}. The key looks a bit like the library key and has a shellfolder subkey with a Attributes d-word set to a0900100. 
After I made a restore point for the operating system, I first tried to change the attributes word to a0800100, which didn’t do anything; then I deleted the shellfolder subkey; which left the Favorites folder but rightclicking offered to delete the folder… but didn’t execute the promise.
Then I deleted the entire key. That left only a vague icon with the same right-click menu, and the same behaviour. So maybe it is some setting in the explorer itself.

Comment: answer not clear

Answer (score 0):

Collating the answers above, here is a [registry file](https://gist.github.com/joshbode/960f381c68c9523825e5) that works without admin access (tested on Win 7) that will hide:

- Favourites
- User Folder
- Libraries

in both Windows Explorer and Open/Save dialogs.

Save it and import it in regedit (Start > Run > `regedit`).